# Virtual methods and static/dynamic alocation

Tags: c++, oop

I wonder why static objects call parent method and dynamic objects child method in this example.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Father {
public:
    virtual string Info() {
        return "I am father";
    }
};

class Son : public Father {
public:
    string Info() {
        return "I am son";
    }
};

int main() {
    Father f = Son();
    cout << f.Info(); // I am father
    Father* pf = new Son();
    cout << pf->Info(); // I am son
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, `Father f = Son()` create object of type Father and copy attributes from object Son (at this case no attributes to copy), so `Father * pf = new Son()` receives pointer to object Son, it actually may be any Father-derived object.

Finally, in your example you have 3 objects. `Father f`, `unnamed object Son()` which copy to `Father f`, and `Father * pf` that points to object of type Son.

Answer (score 7):

It is due to [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) - your `f` is actually an automatically located `Father`, the assigment `Father f = Son()` is actually `Father f = Father(Son())`, thus `f`'s dynamic type is indeed `Father`, and as expected, `Father::Info()` will be invoked.

More info on slicing can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

This is polymorphism. When you allocate an object statically like this:

```
Son son();
```

You know at compile time that `son` is of type `Son`. If you allocate it dynamically you have a choice of storing `Son` objects in `Son` pointers or `Father` pointers. If you store them in `Son` pointers then it's the same as above. However if you store `Son` objects in `Father` type pointers:

```
Father* ptr = new Son()
```

then the compiler has no way of knowing which type of object `Father` pointer is pointing at. So at run time when it finds out it calls the appropriate version of `Info`.